# Conceptual HTTPS/HTTP question for golang repository

Tags: http, go, devops, http2

I have a Gateway API that is built with Golang. We use the "net/http" library documented here https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#example-ListenAndServeTLS. This service has HTTPS connection set up. The connections to my ELB’s use HTTPS because I use TLS termination. So this one Gateway API  has the ssl cert. But then passes the connection to a regular HTTP connection to the other instances.

In short, the Gateway API has HTTPs support, but the services connected to my Gateway API uses HTTP.

When I check my UI services, It shows that we are using HTTP 1.1 still. However from Golang's documentation the package "net/http" should provide HTTP 2.0 support automatically.

Do I need to upgrade my internal services to use HTTPs instead of HTTP in order to use http 2.0?

Sorry If this post comes off as ignorant or rude. I really appreciate anyone taking there time to read this, and am willing to provide any more information that Is needed.

Comment: When you say your "UI services", what do you mean? I get the impression that browsers will want to [only use TLS for HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption).

Answer (score 1):

http2 include h2(TLS) h2c(no TLS), net/http use h2 default when `ListenAndServeTLS`.

if you use http, net/http not use h2c, but http1.1 [currently no browser supports HTTP/2 unencrypted](https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption)

becase net/http don't support h2c default, if you want use h2c(non-TLS version of HTTP/2):

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20220421235706-1d1ef9303861/http2/h2c